# App able to take pictures without permission?

Tags: android, permissions

I have installed an app from a web page (not from the playstore). Every time I open the app, I have the feeling it is taking pics. The screen disappears for milliseconds and comes back. This behavior is only on that specific app and not others. I can't describe it better. I must use this app (my employer want it). Is an app technically able to take pics even if I do not give permission?

Comment: u can check the settings of the app and the permissions. odds are, its just really poor design. without a permission, the API cant be called

Comment: If the app targets an api level below 23, it doesn't need to ask for permissions. But you could still disable the permission in the app settings and see if the app crashes. If it doesn't declare the permission it won't be able to take a picture without any root privileges. I hope it's not your private phone you had to install the app on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Also, you don't need to do anything with the UI to take pictures.  It can be done without you ever knowing, if the app has the proper permissions.  Its more likely to be bad UI code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If your device Android version >= 6.0 (Marshmallow, Nougat, Oreo, Pie)

Answer: **No.** Without your permission for access camera, The app **cant** take pics

- If your device Android version < 6.0 (Lollipop, KitKat, Jelly Bean, Etc:)

Answer: **YES.** Without your permission for access camera, The app **CAN** take pics

This will be helpful
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: Thank you very much for the link and your answer.

Comment: I’m happy to help